# How to return different types?

Tags: c#

```
  public static string k;

  private static List<int> G(List<int> a)
  {
      string sentence = "0 55   6";
      string pattern = @"[0-9]+";

      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

      List<int> not = new List<int>();

      // foreach match i add it to my list
      foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence))
      {
          k = match.Value;
          int notman = Int32.Parse(k);
          not.Add(notman);
      }

      // turn my list into array
      int[] notarray = not.ToArray();

      // trying to return int[] array;
      return notarray;
 }
```

So i input my `List<<int>int>` in this method but i want to return it as a `int[]` array. Any way to return `int[]` *array* back to main method
? im trying to convert it so i can add `array[0] + array[1]` and repeat.

Comment: private static int[] G(List<int> a) ??

Comment: change the method signature so it returns an array of int instead of a list of int

Comment: What are you doing with your "a"? I cant see any reference to it in your code.

Comment: If you want to be able to calculate the sum of all the values in the list you can do `var sum = myList.Sum();` directly. Apart from that a List also functions as an array so `myList[0] + myList[1]` and repeat works perfectly fine for Lists. The reason your code is not working is because the return type is `List<int>` but you're returning an int Array.

Comment: private static IEnumerable<int> G(List<int> a) - the best solving.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you want a `int[]` (array of integers e.g. `new int[] {0, 55, 6}`) from given `string` (say, `"0 55   6"`). If it's your case you can try *Linq*

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 private static int[] G(string sentence) {
   return Regex
     .Matches(sentence, @"\-?[0-9]+")          // \-? - if we accept negative numbers
     .OfType<Match>()                          // Matches collection to IEnumerable<Match>
     .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))  // each Match to int
     .ToArray();                               // Materialize to array
 }

 ...

 // result == {0, 55, 6}
 int[] result = G("0 55   6");
```

Finally, if you want to `Sum` the items o the array up, add *Linq*'s `Sum()`

```
 int sum = G("0 55   6").Sum(); // 61 == 0 + 55 + 6
```

Comment: I would suggest using `Cast` instead of `OfType`?

Comment: @NetMage: Since `Matches` returns collection which contains items of `Match` type only, `Cast<Match>()` and `OfType<Match>()` are equal in the context.

Comment: Except `OfType` is slower to considerably slower and implies you expect some items to not be of the right type.